# Can I get my users data (device, browser) from when they fill form PHP Mailer

Tags: php, html, forms, browser, phpmailer

I need to get my users data such as the browser, and device they are using from when they fill in the form on my website. I am using Php Mailer so can you please help me on how to do this?

Thank you

Ive tried doing it however I don't know how to include it into my Phpmailer file

Comment: Use `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']`

Comment: PhpMailer is the library you use to generate and submit an email message. The contents of the message are not something in its scope.

Answer (score 1):

Using `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` you can get information about the browser and the operating system.

> $_SERVER is an array containing information such as headers, paths,
> and script locations. The entries in this array are created by the web
> server, therefore there is no guarantee that every web server will
> provide any of these

You can find useful information [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) and [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php)